# Template Layouts folder is empty

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, layouts

I am following [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179916%28v=office.15%29.aspx). It makes use of the folder `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS`, but mine only contains a ClientBin folder and not any of the required JavaScript files. Am I missing something?
I am using Windows 7 and VS 2013.
Thanks.

Comment: did you install the SharePoint server? looks like you just install the VS.

Comment: I'm not sure how to because I'm not using Windows Server (I get an appropriate error)

Comment: I see no where in that tutorial where they ask you to do anything in the layouts folder, except from loading scripts from in in script-tags. Those script will load by the browser from your SharePoint server at the time you deploy your app

Comment: It's at around 3:30 of the associated video

Answer (score 0):

the tutorial you are following is referencing a file only available on the SharePoint server, so you will not find it on your machine

however, since it is a file located in the layouts folder, you can get there through the browser and download it. use your own domain, or go ahead and "steal" it from spsdemo

e.g.

http://www.spsdemo.com/_layouts/15/sp.ui.controls.js
http://www.spsdemo.com/_layouts/15/sp.ui.controls.debug.js